# Loading Screen not working in Blackberry?

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, popup

I want to implement a loading screen in blackberry. I try the code from following [Support forum link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808) using following code

```
PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
                           //**Segment 1** here i write the code for  network call
                                    }
                           }, "please wait");
                     // **Segment 2**:Here processing the data get from network call
```

the problem is the segment 2 works before completing the segment 1. I also try the following code

```
HorizontalFieldManager popHF = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    popHF.add(new LabelField("Pls wait..."));
    final PopupScreen waitScreen = new PopupScreen(popHF);
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run() 
        {

            synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(waitScreen);
            }
           // **Segment 1**Here Some Network Call 

          synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(waitScreen);

            }
         }
     }.start();
     // **Segment 2**:Here processing the data get from network call
```

the same problem arises. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it depends on what you're doing in segment 2. If there is no UI actions, then just move segment 2 inside the thread that makes http call. e.g.:

```
final PopupScreen waitScreen = new PopupScreen(popHF);
new Thread()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(waitScreen);
        }
        // **Segment 1**Here Some Network Call

        // **Segment 2**:Here processing the data get from network call

        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(waitScreen);
        }
     }
 }.start();
```

But if there are UI actions inside of segment 2, then call it on UI thread, right after you pop off the wait screen:

```
final PopupScreen waitScreen = new PopupScreen(popHF);
new Thread()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(waitScreen);
        }
        // **Segment 1**Here Some Network Call

        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(waitScreen);
            // **Segment 2**:Here processing the data get from network call
        }
     }
 }.start();
```

Comment: Great. This works fine. I want to add the ui components. so i use the second methode.